Is there a way to flip the parent/child data in an instance of SObject without a new SOQL query?
I have the following SOQL:

    public List<B25__Resource__c> getByIds(Set<Id> resourceIds) {
        return [
                SELECT Id, B25__Parent__c,
                        B25__Parent__r.Id, B25__Parent__r.B25__Parent__c,  B25__Parent__r.B25__Resource_Type__c, B25__Parent__r.B25__Resource_Type__r.Name,
                        B25__Parent__r.DestinationCodes__c, B25__Parent__r.Residence__c,
                        B25__Resource_Type__c, B25__Resource_Type__r.Name,
                        DestinationCodes__c, Residence__c, (
                            SELECT Id, B25__Parent__c,
                                    B25__Parent__r.Id, B25__Parent__r.B25__Parent__c,  B25__Parent__r.B25__Resource_Type__c, B25__Parent__r.B25__Resource_Type__r.Name,
                                    B25__Parent__r.DestinationCodes__c, B25__Parent__r.Residence__c,
                                    B25__Resource_Type__c, B25__Resource_Type__r.Name,
                                    DestinationCodes__c, Residence__c, (
                                    SELECT Id, B25__Parent__c,
                                            B25__Parent__r.Id, B25__Parent__r.B25__Parent__c,  B25__Parent__r.B25__Resource_Type__c, B25__Parent__r.B25__Resource_Type__r.Name,
                                            B25__Parent__r.DestinationCodes__c, B25__Parent__r.Residence__c,
                                            B25__Resource_Type__c, B25__Resource_Type__r.Name,
                                            DestinationCodes__c, Residence__c
                                    FROM B25__Children__r
                            )
                            FROM B25__Children__r
                    )
                FROM B25__Resource__c
                WHERE Id IN :resourceIds
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
        ];
    }

It returns the expected results and for most of the solution, the data is organized exactly as I need it to be.
However, there are portions of the solution which expect to receive a collection of the parent, with the current records collected as children.   The working solution solves this by making an additional SOQL query.
However, this being Salesforce and queries being limited, it seems to me a better solution would be either to (1) refactor the rest of solution (which can be complicated and risky) or to somehow "flip" the data which came out of this query, such that B25__Parent__r becomes the top-level record and the current records become instances of B25__Children__r.
Is there a good way to do this?

You can do this by setting up an array of Map<String, Object> with necessary hierarchy that has the required structure, based on the queried data, then JSON serializing then deserializing to the required collection of parent SObject. However, you may run into issues with heap space if you have large numbers of SObjects that need a lot of populated fields, and it may just be easier to do the query...

@PhilW, thanks for the response.  I was thinking about doing it that way, but between creating code which needs to be maintained, concern how well serializing/deserializing will perform, and memory, not crazy about that idea.... I was hoping there might be a native Apex method for this....

@BrianKessler optimization for the sake of optimization is generally a waste of time. If there are no performance issues with the current solution and you aren't near the SOQL limit during this transaction then the extra query is no big deal today and not worth solving for. Alternatively you could also consider creating a wrapper object to hold the data in a different format, and use that wrapper instead of the sObject

@MorganMarchese, I'm also trying to deal with some data inconsistency issues resulting from multiple queries for essentially the same data, which makes it difficult to maintain and enhance this solution because then we need to find and update all the queries.  Using a wrapper could be a good idea, but that means touching much more of the solution.
